# laravel how to order by created date in yajra datatable

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I want to sort datatable by created date, in the same time to display date in a special format
I tried the code below but didn't work, the problem is I can display date but as in text in the format D d M-Y, I need to sort date as date not as a text

controller

```
        ->addColumn('created_at', function ($data) {
                       return [
                               'display' => date('D d M-Y', strtotime($data->created_at)),
                               'timestamp' => ($data->created_at)
                           ];
                          })
```

jquery:

```
            { name: ' order_date', data: { '_': ' order_date.display', 'sort': ' order_date.timestamp' 
            } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the order in the js.

```
  order: [[ 1, 'desc' ]],
```

Where 1 is the col position.

Comment: the problem is I can display date but as in text in the format D d M-Y, I need to sort date as date not as a text

Comment: then use  "order": [] and order the query in the controller.

Comment: I think you didnt get what I want, the solution is here but ddint get it https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1404

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps to resolved issue

Controller

```html
  return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->editColumn('created_at', function ($user) {
                return [
                    'display' => e($user->created_at->format('m/d/Y')),
                    'timestamp' => $user->created_at->timestamp
                ];
            })
            ->filterColumn('created_at', function ($query, $keyword) {
                $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m/%d/%Y') LIKE ?", ["%$keyword%"]);
            })
            ->make(true);
```

Js

```js
columns: [
        {
            data: 'index',
            defaultContent: '',
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false,
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1; //auto increment
            }
        },
        {data: 'site_name', name: 'site_name'},
        {data: 'site_url', name: 'site_url'},
        {data: 'key', name: 'key', defaultContent: "-"},
        {
            data: 'created_at',
            type: 'num',
            render: {
                _: 'display',
                sort: 'timestamp'
            }
        },
        {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
    ],
   
    order: [[4, "DESC"]] //column indexes is zero based
```

Answer (score 1):

(100% Working)
Controller

```
 ->editColumn('created', function ($user) {
                return [
                    'display' => date("h:i A, d/m/Y",strtotime($user->created)),
                    'timestamp' => strtotime($user->created)
                ];
            })
```

JS

```
 { 
        'name': 'created', 
        'data': { 
                    '_': 'created.display', 
                    'sort': 'created.timestamp' 
         } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input `$data` of `Datatables::of($data)` is  `Collection` (not `Builder`), then you need to change from

```
 { name: ' order_date', data: { '_': ' order_date.display', 'sort': ' order_date.timestamp' 
            } }
```

to

```
{ name: ' order_date.timestamp', data: { '_': 'display', 'sort': 'timestamp' 
                } }
```

By doing this, the `getSorter()` from `Yajra\DataTables\CollectionDataTable` can extract the right property, which is `order_date.timestamp` in your example, to process sorting.

Ref: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1404#issuecomment-506623825

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following procedure (It's working)

```
DataTables::eloquent($query)
->order(function ($q){
                $q->orderBy('ReceiveDate','desc');
            })->addColumn('ReceiveDate', function ($data) {
                return date('d-M-Y H:i:s', strtotime($data->ReceiveDate));
            })->make();
```

In frontend simply keep object like this:

```
            {
                data: 'ReceiveDate',
                title: "Receive Date",
            }
```